# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt[]{n}+n\sqrt[]{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Compute

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt[]{n}+n\sqrt[]{n+1}}$

Comment: Maybe try writing it as $1 \over \sqrt n\sqrt {n+1}(\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n)$

Comment: Also, change the index of summation to $n$ from $k$.

Answer (score 14):

The sum is $1$.  Multiply the summand up and down by $(n+1) \sqrt{n}-n \sqrt{n+1}$; the denominator becomes $n (n+1)$.  The sum then becomes

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$$

which is a telescoping sum.

Comment: @user85751: you're welcome.  If you did in fact find this answer useful, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Putting $n=\tan^2\theta,$

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt n+n\sqrt {n+1}}=\frac1{\sec^2\theta\tan\theta+\tan^2\theta\sec\theta}$$

$$=\frac1{\sec\theta\tan\theta(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)}=\frac{\sec\theta-\tan\theta}{\sec\theta\tan\theta}(\text{ as }\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta=1)$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt n+n\sqrt {n+1}}=\frac{\sec\theta-\tan\theta}{\sec\theta\tan\theta}=\frac1{\tan\theta}-\frac1{\sec\theta}=\frac1{\sqrt n}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$ which clearly is the $n$th term of a [Telescopic Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)